# Ejecutar método trabaja con widgets desde tarea en 2do plano en Flutter Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, procesos-en-segundo-plano

**Contexto.**
Flutter 3.19.0 y Dart 3.3.0 • DevTools 2.31.1

**Qué estoy haciendo.**
Estoy haciendo pruebas de cómo funcionan las tareas en 2do plano con el paquete [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service). Logré ejecutar con éxito la aplicación de ejemplo ([esta](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service/example))

En resumen, la tarea en 2do plano de este ejemplo hace algo muy simple: obtiene el nombre del dispositivo y el datetime actual y los envía al 1er plano, o sea a la pantalla que ve el usuario.

**Qué quiero hacer.**
He creado el siguiente método: `miControlador.miMetodo(List<File> listaImagenes, StreamController<int> wallpaperStreamController, int imagenActual)`. Mi método cambia el wallpaper del dispositivo usando el paquete [flutter_wallpaper_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wallpaper_manager). Mi método funciona bien si lo ejecuto en 1er plano, presionando un botón:

```
  ElevatedButton(
   onPressed: () {
      miControlador.miMetodo(
       miControlador.listaImagenes,
       miControlador.wallpaperStreamController,
       miControlador.imagenActual,
    )},
   child: Text('Presiona aquí'),
  )
```

Con el fin de que mi método se ejecute en 2do plano, ingenuamente se me ocurrió poner mi método dentro del método `onStart`. Pero no funciona: Cuando presiono el botón para iniciar la tarea en 2do plano sí se muestra la notificación push con el texto *"AWESOME SERVICE Initializing"*, y es todo, ni ejecuta mi método (porque no cambia el wallpaper de mi teléfono), ni la pantalla muestra el datetime proveniente de la tarea en 2do plano.

```
  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
   //...

   MiControlador miControlador = Get.put(MiControlador());
   miControlador.miMetodo(
    miControlador.listaImagenes,
    miControlador.wallpaperStreamController,
    miControlador.imagenActual,
   );

   //...
  }
```

**¿Por qué pasa esto?** Creo que esto pasa porque intento ejecutar un método que pertenece a un controlador de widget desde el contexto de un servicio en 2do plano, y entiendo que esto no es posible, ya que el controlador de widget no está disponible en el contexto del servicio en 2do plano.

¿Qué alternativas tengo para lograr mi objetivo?